# How to change ppk password for Google Cloud Debian Linux server

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords

Someone compromised my .ppk as well as the username and password. They don't have much CLI knowledge so they haven't done any damage yet, but I'm trying to figure out how to change the ssh password for the specific ppk they got access to. I tried doing sudo passwd with a success but now both the old AND new passwords work when logging in. I got the IP of said person with the "last" command and am going to put that in hosts.deny for now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what exactly happened. But if someone was able to to copy a private key file, then changing the passphrase for the private key isn't going to help. You should invalidate the key (i.e. remove it from the server so it can't be used to log in any more), then generate a new key and use that one instead of the old one.

By "ssh password for the specific ppk", I assume you mean the [ssh key passphrase](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/passphrase). The passphrase is used to encrypt the file containing the ssh key. The passphrase isn't sent to the server, and the server has no idea that a passphrase is being used.

If you change the passphrase for an ssh key, then you're just altering the copy of the key file that you have. Nothing changes on the server. If someone else has another copy of the private key file, they can still use that copy of the file.

If one of your key files is compromised, the only reasonable thing to do is to stop using that key. Remove that key from your servers, so it can no longer be used. Generate a new key and use that instead of the old one.

Having said all that, ppk key files are associated with the [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) software package. PuTTY includes a key-generation program named `puttygen`.

For Windows, the [documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey-puttygen) indicates you can load a key file into puttygen, change the passphrase, and save the key again.

On Unix, puttygen is a command-line utility. [The documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/puttygen) indicates you can run:

```
puttygen -P mykey.ppk
```

to change the passphrase for an existing key file.